# My app keeps stopping after updating my phone to android 10

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio

I had an app that worked perfectly in android 9 api 28 but after updating my phone to android 10 api 29, it keeps stopping and when i tried it in android studio emulator android 10 api 29, the emulator fails to load and i get the following error:

Emulator: emulator ERROR VkComminOperations.cpp:496: Failed to create Vulkan instance

then my windows 10 crashes. but when i compile it in android studio emulator with android 9 api 28 or less it works again perfectly. can someone explain what happening here thanks.

Comment: Try to log the error may be any method is deprecated for android 10 or check your build.gradle(app) for target sdk and build tools

Comment: please share error log.

Comment: I dont know why but its working again i had to change targetSdkVersion to 28 intead of 29 and the same for compileSdkVersion 28